# Argument 1 cannot convert from a class to IWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am trying to register the IWebDriver instance in the container the parameter I am passing to it is showing an error.  The error is Argument 1: cannot convert from OlympusUIFramework.DriverManagement.BrowserSetup to OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver

The line the error shows is here
    container.RegisterInstanceAs(BrowserSetUp);

BrowserSetUp is underlined in red

In my BrowserSetUp class I am reading the browser value from the config file.  The value is chrome.  I have an If statement, if the value is chrome instantiate the chrome driver and I am returning the driver
I would like to pass this driver into here as a parameter

```
container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(BrowserSetUp);
```

Why does it error?  Is it because it is trying to pass the class and not the driver?
What is the correct way to do this please?
Thanks,
Riaz

```
Class BrowserSetup

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace OlympusUIFramework.DriverManagement
{
public class BrowserSetup
{        
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public IWebDriver InitiateBrowser(IWebDriver browser, string 
ConfigValue)
    {
        var Browser = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigValue];
        if (Browser == "chrome")
        {
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\\selenium 
browsers\\");
            return driver;
        }
        return driver;           
    }
}
}
```

Class SpecFlowHooks

```
using System.Text;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Olympus.Page;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using BoDi;
using OlympusUIFramework.DriverManagement;

namespace Olympus
{
[Binding]
public class SpecFlowHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;


    public SpecFlowHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateWebDriver()
    {
        // Create and configure a concrete instance of IWebDriver
        //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\\selenium 
browsers\\");
        //{

        //};
        BrowserSetup BrowserSetUp = new BrowserSetup();
        // Make this instance available to all other step definitions
        //container.RegisterInstanceAs(driver);
        //container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);
        container.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(BrowserSetUp);
    }
}
}
```

Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <add key="browser" value="chrome"/>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign a instance of `OlympusUIFramework.DriverManagement.BrowserSetup` to a variable, field or argument that only takes instances of classes that implement `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver`.

BrowserSetup evidentally does not implement that Interface, so no implicit cast on that grounds can happen. And the Compiler failed to find any other implicit cast betwen those two types. So now it is your job to fix that.

You class `BrowserSetup` is a Aggregate Composite that contains a IWebDriver reference. That is not the same as it being a IWebDriver. You either need inheritance for this, or assign the value of `driver` (at wich point I am unsure why BrowserSetup even exists).

I get teh feeling you wanted a Static class that uses the static InitiateBrowser function as a factory method.
That `driver` reference should definitely not be public. And either you wanted to also implement a singleton, or it should not even be here